# Creating pagination for 100 dynamically created rows in pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination, createelement

EDIT: As was pointed out, I should be using unique ID's. My dynamically created class now has the `cardRowClass` class and the `id` has been modified to be `cardRowId + i` where `i` is the for loop variable. I've changed the code below accordingly.

I've got 100 rows of data being created dynamically in JavaScript using a `for` loop containing the following snippet:

```
var cardRow = document.createElement("div");
cardRow.setAttribute("class", "row justify-content-center cardRowClass");
cardRow.setAttribute("id", "cardRowId" + i);
cardRow.setAttribute("align", "center");

document.getElementById("cardData").appendChild(cardRow);
```

I'm trying to figure out different ways to create pagination for these dynamically created rows that all have the same ID. I aim to create 10 rows per page, ideally using pure JS. I do have a variable `i` which increments, so perhaps another ID can be added using that variable?

I've considered the following CSS approach, but I don't think it's going to work for doing anything but just showing the first 10 results.

```
.cardRowClass {
 display: none;
}

.cardRowClass:nth-child(-n+10) {
    display: flex;
}
```

Is it possible to target the `n-th` child selector with JS i.e. every time I click NEXT I change the **pseudocode** `nth-child(1 to 10)` to `nth-child(1+10 to 11+10), nth-child(11+10 to 21+10)`and so on? Perhaps using `document.getElementById("cardRowId").something = ...`?

This approach doesn't seem correct at all, so any suggestions for alternate approaches are very welcome.

Comment: *"all have the same ID"* .... ID's must be unique by definition

Comment: @charlietfl Good point, I've changed it to `cardRowClass` with the same properties, and my ID is now defined by `cardRowId + i`